# Ubuntu and Xorg - How to run .sh file when I log in to the system?

Tags: scripts, startup

I want to run `google-chrome --app=URL` in my `.sh` file in the moment when I log in to the my account. I don't want to see a terminal window.

Comment: "Note: I don't want the application to start after a user logs in but rather when the computer starts."

I want the application to start after a user logs in.

Comment: Which Desktop Manager are you using? Ubuntu GNOME? If you don't know what I mean, then which Ubuntu version are you using (16.04, 17.10, etc.)? As the answer may vary in this case depending on your installation.

Comment: @Videonauth: Wouldn't it be far simpler to add an application launcher to the auto-start list of the user?

Comment: Yes @DavidFoerster might be simpler, sometimes I post what first comes to mind as a solution, but sure there are always many ways leading to rome :)